# Stream slicing operation in block cipher and side-channel attack

Tags: side-channel-attack

My symmetric block cipher works kind of like a stream cipher, but it works on $128$-bit blocks. It generates a $128$-bit block in every round. And at the end of the round, I have to slice it into two blocks and add them together. I mean after each round we take first $a$ bits and second $b$ bits of $128$-bit block and then compute $b+a$. $a$ is equal to $0$ to $127$, it is computed from the key schedule and should be indistinguishable from random. But such slicing can be attacked by the side-channel attack. Attacker can find $a_{0}$, $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$ and so on for every round.

But my cipher works like a stream cipher. That means it computes bit by bit in steps and then combines them into a block. Normally I'm making $128$-bit block with this, for $i$ in the range $0-127$:

$ct=0$

$ct=ct+bitv$

$bitv$ is a bit value $0$ or $1$ and it comes from cipher function. We are just making some binary string/block here. My idea is to not slicing block in the end but first compute first $a$ bits like a string for $i$ in the range $0-a$, where $a$ is some indistinguishable from a random number from the key schedule:

1. $a=a+btiv$

and then compute the rest of the string for $i$ in range $a+1-127$ as:

2. $ct = ct + bitv + a$

Anyway, we still have to make for example two loops "for". First for $i$ in range $0-a$ and second in range $a+1-127$ inside the round. Is it possible to attack it by the side-channel attack? Can the attacker detect when the first loop will end and the second will start and then find $a$?

Comment: The key schedule should be considered secret. Your side channel reveals the key schedule. Even if your key schedule is indistinguishable from random an attacker can usually still derive the key. Since your key schedule is the same as your encryption algorithm it would be inherently vulnerable to the same attacks as your encryption. Even if it isn't, your key schedule probably still isn't a secure hashing algorithm and therefore the original key can even be obtained. Also, most modes of operation are broken even if only the key schedule is revealed but not the key.

Comment: So side-channel attack is possible even in this case? Attacker can find that one loop was in range $0$ to $a$ and guess $a$? In the end round is making the same number of iterations ($128$), but there is that loop change in between.

Answer (score 1):

The key schedule should be considered secret. Your side channel reveals the key schedule. Even if your key schedule is indistinguishable from random an attacker can usually still derive the key. Since your key schedule is the same as your encryption algorithm it would be inherently vulnerable to the same attacks as your encryption. Even if it isn't, your key schedule probably still isn't a secure hashing algorithm and therefore the original key can even be obtained.

*Most (all) modes of operation are broken even if only the key schedule is revealed but not the key. Some are (slightly) less broken than others.*

Side-channels are enabled by *any* data-dependent memory accesses. Even if the total number of memory accesses is constant, this cannot be assumed to provide security. If I perform some computation on bits $1,...,a$ and I perform another (possibly the same) computation on bits $a+1,...,128$ I've just performed a different pattern of memory accesses, and revealed the value of $a$ (which is nearly impossible to fix in implementation). Nevermind the fact that `for` loops require an `if` statement to tell when to break (the compiler adds it implicitly). That means that you've allowed *cache-timing*, *branch-prediction*, ***and*** *branch-timing* attacks.

#### On the impact of various side-channels

- Cache-timing is fixable in hardware that doesn't cache memory. Memory caching exists in all major architectures, and can't really by bypassed or disabled.
- Branch-prediction (also known as speculative execution) only exists in hardware that tries to predict branching. This behavior exists in all major architectures, and can't be bypassed.
- Branch-timing attacks, however, are hardware-agnostic and will affect every system identically... For this reason these are among the worst of all side-channels.

*All side-channel attacks, even if hardware-dependent, are considered crippling to a secure cryptographic implementation.*

Comment: Maybe it is question on separate topic - but is there way to do what I want to do without risking an side-channel attack? Maybe lookup table which transform my let's say 8-bit stream into 8 bit output and in the end make one 128-bit block. Rijandel S-box could be fine. I need it to avoid differential and linear cryptanalysis but I think I don't need nothing more than moving bits in blocks. So using Rijandel s-box is even more that I really need. But if s-box is only solution, those used in the AES could be the best. But then what's the point of making new AES-based, probably slower cipher?

Comment: Lookup tables are *the* classic example of an implementation vulnerable to cache-timing attacks. Round constants are the standard way to avoid differential cryptanalysis, and linear cryptanalysis is solved by making your algorithm (specifically the S-box) less linear. Bit shuffling such as what you propose isn't the solution in either case. You *can* avoid side-channels in your bit-shuffling but you'd lose huge amounts of performance (anywhere between 16 and 128 times slower in your case, depending on whether you shuffle bytes or individual bits).

Comment: `But if s-box is only solution, those used in the AES could be the best. But then what's the point of making new AES-based, probably slower cipher?` Welcome to the world of cryptography. AES is well-understood. AES is fast. AES is secure within well-known bounds. AES is implemented without side-channels. Your algorithm can change any of those without you realizing. If your question is "what's the point" I'm asking the same thing. There are a million reasons not to use homebrew crypto, and you just described about half of them.

Comment: Although making homebrew *can* be a good learning exercise which is why I haven't simply told you to use Serpent, TwoFish, Camellia, or another well-understood algorithm.

Comment: I got many motivations to make that cipher. Obviously, none of them are for practical applications as yet (if I had to really encrypt something, I would use AES for example). I know that in cryptography first you have to make reasonable scientific publication, then no one can broke your cipher and even then there is no certainty that the cipher is secure.

Comment: But I can simplify problem of designing that cipher. I have to avoid exactly the same problems which has Lehmer random number generators, which are using a modulus $m$ which is a power of $2$. I asked about it here:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/84011/lehmer-random-number-generator-cipher/84013?noredirect=1#comment184652_84013
At least problem is clear. I don't know if it is even possible, to make such encryption scheme secure, but it is clear defined and using such a "toy" Lehmer cipher we can prove many properties and security or weaknesses of my cipher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113630/discussion-between-tom-and-serpent27).